# Transform binary columns to 1 row in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I am quite new to R and have only basic skills so far and even though I checked functions like `melt()` and `gather()` they somehow do not work for me.
What I want to do is transform such data (considering that all options on HAS House /Renting and Homeless are only `1` and `0`and you cannot have more than `1` (you cannot be Renting and Homeless at the same time)

Eg.

```
Passenger ID ///  Has Own House /// Renting /// Homeless /// Age /// Gender
1                  1                 0           0            21      Male
2                  0                 1           0            24     Female
```

I want this data to look like this:

```
Passenger ID /// Housing       /// Age /// Gender
1                Has own house     21      Male
2                Renting           24      Female
```

And when it comes to forecasting - please can you advise whether the above method (with the binary factors) will work better in terms of speed or having all in 1 column will be better solution?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If `df` is your data.frame, you can make something like `df$HOUSING = apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) names(df)[2:4][which(x==1)])`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
library(tidyverse)
# importing your data
df <- read_table("Passenger_ID    Has_Own_House   Renting   Homeless   Age Gender
1                  1                 0           0     21      Male
2                  0                 1           0     24     Female")
```

and run:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Housing, value, -Passenger_ID, -Age, -Gender) %>% 
  filter(value==1) %>% 
  select(-value)
```

the output is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Passenger_ID   Age Gender Housing      
#          <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>        
# 1            1    21 Male   Has_Own_House
# 2            2    24 Female Renting
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R with ifelse:

```
# Load Data
dat <- structure(list(Passenger_ID = 1:2, Has_Own_House = c(1L, 0L),
         Renting = 0:1, Homeless = c(0L, 0L), Age = c(21L, 24L), Gender = structure(c(2L,
         1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Passenger_ID",
         "Has_Own_House", "Renting", "Homeless", "Age", "Gender"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
         -2L))

# Assign new column "Housing" based on testing nested ifelse statements:

dat2 <- within(dat, Housing <- ifelse(Has_Own_House==1, "Has_Own_House",
                           ifelse(Renting==1, "Renting",
                           ifelse(Homeless==1, "Homeless", NA))))

# Remove extra columns
dat2$Has_Own_House <- NULL
dat2$Renting <- NULL
dat2$Homeless <- NULL
```

Yielding

```
>dat2

Passenger_ID Age Gender       Housing
       1  21   Male Has_Own_House
       2  24 Female       Renting
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can simply assign a new column just in one line by `apply`ing to all lines (`1` argument) of the data frame a function returning the appropriate column name (where the value is 1 thanks to `which`):

```
df = data.frame('Passenger ID' = 1:5,
                'Has Own House' = c(1,0,0,1,0),
                'Renting' = c(0,1,0,0,0),
                'Homeless' = c(0,0,1,0,1),
                'Age'=21:25,
                'Gender' = c('Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'))


df$HOUSING = apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) names(df)[2:4][which(x==1)])
df
#   Passenger.ID Has.Own.House Renting Homeless Age Gender       HOUSING
# 1            1             1       0        0  21   Male Has.Own.House
# 2            2             0       1        0  22 Female       Renting
# 3            3             0       0        1  23   Male      Homeless
# 4            4             1       0        0  24 Female Has.Own.House
# 5            5             0       0        1  25   Male      Homeless
```